# Java: add statement in argument of method

Tags: java, methods

I was looking at this piece of code and can not understand what the .add statement is doing (fromCity) and (toCity) is just Strings?

```
getDestinations(fromCity).add(toCity);
```

Method:

```
public ArrayList<String> getDestinations(String fromCity)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called `chaining of method calls`. You are invoking the next method on the return value of the previous method.

So, the `getDestinations()` method returns you a `ArrayList`, now instead of storing your returning value, you are invoking the `add` method of the `ArrayList` on the method call.

```
getDestinations(fromCity).add(toCity);
```

This is equivalent to: -

```
ArrayList<String> list = getDestination(fromCity) // returns `ArrayList - list`
list.add(toCity) // invoke `add` method on returned arraylist.
```

Similarly **you can chain method calls** upto any lavel: -

```
meth1(parameter1).meth2(param3).meth3(param3);
```

Answer (score 3):

`getDestinations(fromCity)` returning an `ArrayList`

`add` method is array list method which is adding an element to it.

In other words:

```
ArrayLisst<String> destList = getDestinations(fromCity);
destList.add(toCity);
```

Answer (score 2):

It adds the string `toCity` to the `ArrayList<String>` returned by `getDestinations(fromCity)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `.add()` isn't attached to `fromCity`, but to the method call `getDestinations(fromCity)`.
From the method declaration you can see that `getDestinations(String fromCity)` returns an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), and those have an [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

Please check

```
public ArrayList<String> getDestinations(String fromCity)
```

-return a ArrayList which can have set of Strings *

```
getDestinations(fromCity).add(toCity);
```

**---here getdestination is called it returns arraylist  and  add a String(fromcity) to arraylist**